# Angular integration with homepage

Tags: themes, javascript

I have a requirement from client that they want to serve wordpress' front page as home page to `angular` project. It means if user clicks any link on `WP's` home page, then it will redirect to `angular` project's internal `urls`.

Once landed on `angular's` page they should be able to go back to any pages from where it was redirected (may be `angular` or `WP` page)

**Things I followed so far:**

I managed to install local angular setup inside `worpdress directory`.

currently directory pattern is looking like

`www.example.com/wordpress/angular`

on clicking `WP's` menu link it will redirect to

`www.example.com/wordpress/angular/#/some-url`

(I am struggling to remove `'angular'` directory name for `Url` though)

on back, it is going to wordpress homepage.

But there are lot of `routing` issues due to `parent` and `child`directory's different routing system. I am trying to maintain as all redirection should be like `SPA`.

Is there any better way to make such integration?

I am using `WP version 5.2.3` and `Angular 6.x`